# Preferentially match shorter token in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm currently attempting to write a [UCUM](http://unitsofmeasure.org/trac/) parser using ANTLR4. My current approach has involved defining every valid unit and prefix as a token.

Here's a very small subset of the defined tokens. I could make a cut-down version of the grammar as an example, but it seems like it shouldn't be necessary to resolve this problem (or to point out that I'm going about this entirely the wrong way).

```
MILLI_OR_METRE:     'm' ;
OSMOLE:             'osm' ;
MONTH:              'mo' ;
SECOND:             's' ;
```

One of the standard testcases is `mosm`, from which the lexer should generate the token stream `MILLI_OR_METRE OSMOLE`. Unfortunately, because ANTLR preferentially matches longer tokens, it generates the token stream `MONTH SECOND MILLI_OR_METRE`, which then causes the parser to raise an error.

Is it possible to make an ANTLR4 lexer try to match using shorter tokens first? Adding lookahead-type rules to `MONTH` isn't a great solution, as there are all sorts of potential lexing conflicts that I'd need to take account of (for example `mol` being lexed as `MONTH LITRE` instead of `MOLE` and so on).

EDIT:

StefanA below is of course correct; this is a job for a parser capable of backtracking (eg. recursive descent, packrat, PEG and probably various others... Coco/R is one reasonable package to do this). In an attempt to avoid adding a dependency on another parser generator (or moving other bits of the project from ANTLR to this new generator) I've hacked my way around the problem like this:

```
MONTH:  'mo' { _input.La(1) != 's' && _input.La(1) != 'l' && _input.La(1) != '_' }? ;

// (note: this is a C# project; java would use _input.LA instead)
```

but this isn't really a very extensible or maintainable solution, and like as not will have introduced other subtle issues I've not come across yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem does not require smaller tokens to be preferred (In this case MONTH would never be matched). You need a backtracking behaviour dependent on the text being matched or not. Right?

ANTLR separates tokenization and parsing strictly. Consequently every solution to your problem will seem like a hack.

However other parser generators are specialized on problems like yours. Packrat Parsers (PEG) are backtracking and allow tokenization on the fly. Try out [parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled) for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah, I had a nasty feeling this would be the case. I'm trying to avoid using a different parser generator, as this particular project already uses ANTLR for another component and it would be nice not to pile on the dependencies.

Comment: True, PEG (scanner-less parser) seems more appropriate here.

Comment: So, I hacked my way around the issue in the end using lookahead semantic predicates (and described my solution above), but I've accepted your answer anyway as it is the most sensible way to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that the question is not being framed correctly.

> I'm currently attempting to write a UCUM parser using ANTLR4. My current approach has involved defining every valid unit and prefix as a token.

But, according to the UCUM:

> The expression syntax of The Unified Code for Units of Measure generates an infinite number of codes with the consequence that it is impossible to compile a table of all valid units.

The most to expect from the lexer is an unambiguous identification of the measurement string without regard to its semantic value.  Similarly, a parser alone will be unable to validly select between unit sequences like `MONTH LITRE` and `MOLE` - both could reasonably apply to a leak rate - unless the problem space is statically constrained in the parser definition.

A heuristic, structural (explicitly identifying the problem space) or contextual (considering the relative nature of other units in the problem space), is most likely required to select the correct unit interpretation.

The best tool to use is the one that puts you in the best position to implement the heuristics necessary to disambiguate the unit strings.  Antlr *could* do it using parse-tree walkers.  Whether that is the appropriate approach requires further analysis.

Comment: Using a parsing algorithm capable of backtracking would resolve the issue i posted; `MILLI_OR_METRE OSMOLE` is a valid string in the grammar and `MONTH SECOND MILLI_OR_METRE` is not. This isn't an artefact of UCUM.